# How can I decrypt a string using AES algorithm in c#?

Tags: c#, aes, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

I have an encrypted string from one of our customers.
This string was encrypted using the AES method in Java.

The only thing I have is the key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" (24 chars) and the encrypted text: "56e84e9f6344826bcfa439cda09e5e96" (32 chars). (This really is the only data I have)

I can't seem to find a method to decrypt this string.

Could anyone provide me with a working example.