# Encrypt in ColdFusion, Decrypt in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, coldfusion-9

I have a string that was encrypted with ColdFusion 9 using the [encrypt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c2f.html) function. The problem is that the function was called using the the UUEncode algorithm (default).  I need to decrypt this value using C#.  All of the samples use Base64 encoding.  Any ideas?

Here's what was used in ColdFusion

```
 <cfset encryptionKey = generateSecretKey( "AES" ) />

 <cfset pwhash = encrypt( user_password,
                          encryptionKey,
                          "AES",
                          "UU"
                       ) />
```

I have the resulting values. I also have the resulting decrypted value for one user, so I could compare it with something in C#.  I need to decrypt the passwords for all users in a system.

Comment: A quick Google search reveals a [few](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/12/18/63486.aspx) [results](http://www.nullskull.com/a/237/uuencode-and-uudecode-in-vbnet-and-c.aspx) [for](http://sdheadaches.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/uuencode-and-uudecode-in-cnet.html) UUDecode, did you try any of them?

Comment: Sure but I don't know how that fits in.

Comment: Well you said in your question that the data was encrypted with UUEncode, so logically you can decrypt with UUDecode right?

Comment: Yes, but there's more to it than UU.  The Cold Fusion is using UU encoding in an AES encryption method, with a key.  So what about all the other pieces?  I know UU Encoding/Decoding is part of it, but not sure how it plays in, i.e. what other steps to take to make it fit into decryption code that uses ASCII, or something else.

Comment: As long as you can decode the UU value into bytes, [the other example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186665/encrypt-in-coldfusion-and-decrypt-in-c-sharp/26189072?noredirect=1#comment63832693_26189072) should work correctly. Just replace `SomeMethodToConvertHexToBytes` with whatever method you are using to decode the encrypted value into bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Ok worked!  I found a conversion of UUencode here  http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/12/18/63486.aspx

Comment: Cool. Though side note, passwords should really be *hashed*, not encrypted ;-)

Comment: Agreed.  I didn't write the existing CF code, but had to decrypt what was already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Leigh and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186665/encrypt-in-coldfusion-and-decrypt-in-c-sharp/26189072?noredirect=1#comment63832693_26189072) I was able to implement a solution using [this C# implementation of UUEncoding](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2005/12/18/63486.aspx) like so:

```
public class PasswordHelper
{               
    public string DecryptAES(string encryptedString, string Key)
    {

        //First write to memory
        MemoryStream mmsStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter srwTemp = new StreamWriter(mmsStream);
        //sBuffer is my encodedtext.
        srwTemp.Write(encryptedString);
        srwTemp.Flush();
        mmsStream.Position = 0;

        MemoryStream outstream = new MemoryStream();

        //CallingUUDecode
        Codecs.UUDecode(mmsStream, outstream);         

        //Extract the bytes of each of the values
        byte[] input = outstream.ToArray();
        byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);

        string decryptedText = null;

        using (RijndaelManaged algorithm = new RijndaelManaged())
        {

            // initialize settings to match those used by CF
            algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            algorithm.BlockSize = 128;
            algorithm.KeySize = 128;
            algorithm.Key = key;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor();

            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(input))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        decryptedText = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }

}

public static class Codecs
{
    static readonly byte[] UUEncMap = new byte[]
    {
      0x60, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27,
      0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F,
      0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,
      0x38, 0x39, 0x3A, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0x3E, 0x3F,
      0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47,
      0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x4E, 0x4F,
      0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57,
      0x58, 0x59, 0x5A, 0x5B, 0x5C, 0x5D, 0x5E, 0x5F
    };

    static readonly byte[] UUDecMap = new byte[]
    {
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
      0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
      0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
      0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F,
      0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27,
      0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F,
      0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,
      0x38, 0x39, 0x3A, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0x3E, 0x3F,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
    };

    public static void UUDecode(System.IO.Stream input, System.IO.Stream output)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("output");

        long len = input.Length;
        if (len == 0)
            return;

        long didx = 0;
        int nextByte = input.ReadByte();
        while (nextByte >= 0)
        {
            // get line length (in number of encoded octets)
            int line_len = UUDecMap[nextByte];

            // ascii printable to 0-63 and 4-byte to 3-byte conversion
            long end = didx + line_len;
            byte A, B, C, D;
            if (end > 2)
            {
                while (didx < end - 2)
                {
                    A = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];
                    B = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];
                    C = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];
                    D = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];

                    output.WriteByte((byte)(((A << 2) & 255) | ((B >> 4) & 3)));
                    output.WriteByte((byte)(((B << 4) & 255) | ((C >> 2) & 15)));
                    output.WriteByte((byte)(((C << 6) & 255) | (D & 63)));
                    didx += 3;
                }
            }

            if (didx < end)
            {
                A = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];
                B = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];
                output.WriteByte((byte)(((A << 2) & 255) | ((B >> 4) & 3)));
                didx++;
            }

            if (didx < end)
            {
                B = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];
                C = UUDecMap[input.ReadByte()];
                output.WriteByte((byte)(((B << 4) & 255) | ((C >> 2) & 15)));
                didx++;
            }

            // skip padding
            do
            {
                nextByte = input.ReadByte();
            }
            while (nextByte >= 0 && nextByte != '\n' && nextByte != '\r');

            // skip end of line
            do
            {
                nextByte = input.ReadByte();
            }
            while (nextByte >= 0 && (nextByte == '\n' || nextByte == '\r'));
        }
    }

    public static void UUEncode(System.IO.Stream input, System.IO.Stream output)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

        if (output == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("output");

        long len = input.Length;
        if (len == 0)
            return;

        int sidx = 0;
        int line_len = 45;
        byte[] nl = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);

        byte A, B, C;
        // split into lines, adding line-length and line terminator
        while (sidx + line_len < len)
        {
            // line length
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[line_len]);

            // 3-byte to 4-byte conversion + 0-63 to ascii printable conversion
            for (int end = sidx + line_len; sidx < end; sidx += 3)
            {
                A = (byte)input.ReadByte();
                B = (byte)input.ReadByte();
                C = (byte)input.ReadByte();

                output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(A >> 2) & 63]);
                output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(B >> 4) & 15 | (A << 4) & 63]);
                output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(C >> 6) & 3 | (B << 2) & 63]);
                output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[C & 63]);
            }

            // line terminator
            for (int idx = 0; idx < nl.Length; idx++)
                output.WriteByte(nl[idx]);
        }

        // line length
        output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[len - sidx]);

        // 3-byte to 4-byte conversion + 0-63 to ascii printable conversion
        while (sidx + 2 < len)
        {
            A = (byte)input.ReadByte();
            B = (byte)input.ReadByte();
            C = (byte)input.ReadByte();

            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(A >> 2) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(B >> 4) & 15 | (A << 4) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(C >> 6) & 3 | (B << 2) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[C & 63]);
            sidx += 3;
        }

        if (sidx < len - 1)
        {
            A = (byte)input.ReadByte();
            B = (byte)input.ReadByte();

            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(A >> 2) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(B >> 4) & 15 | (A << 4) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(B << 2) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[0]);
        }
        else if (sidx < len)
        {
            A = (byte)input.ReadByte();

            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(A >> 2) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[(A << 4) & 63]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[0]);
            output.WriteByte(UUEncMap[0]);
        }

        // line terminator
        for (int idx = 0; idx < nl.Length; idx++)
            output.WriteByte(nl[idx]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The KDE Codec part from geekswithblogs have some translation error. noted in the comment of the article.