# How to decrypt a C# encrypted AES string in java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I have a string that encrypted in java by "AES", Now i need decrypt in my C# program (I have the key)

Now i need decrypt in C#.How do I decode it into the C#?

my Encrypte and Decrypt in java :

```
public class AES {

public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
    byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
    return toHex(result);
}

public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {      
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());       
    byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
    //ggggg
    byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
    return new String(result);
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {             
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secrand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
    secrand.setSeed(seed);
    keygen.init(128, secrand);
    SecretKey seckey = keygen.generateKey();
    byte[] rawKey = seckey.getEncoded();
    return rawKey;
}


private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    //0000
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);        
    return decrypted;
}

public static String toHex(String txt) {
    return toHex(txt.getBytes());
}
public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    return new String(toByte(hex));
}

public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
    int len = hexString.length()/2;
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
    return result;
}

public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}
```

and

```
          try {
            String plaintext = "Hello world", key = "111";
            String ciphertext = AES.encrypt(key, plaintext);
            Log.i("ddddddd",ciphertext);

            String plaintext2 = AES.decrypt(key, ciphertext);
            Log.i("ddddddd","Encrypting '" + plaintext +
                               "' yields: (" + ciphertext.length() + ") " + ciphertext);
            Log.i("ddddddd","Decrypting it yields: " + plaintext2);
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Now i need decrypt in C#.How do I decode it into the C#?

Comment: Have you **googled**?

Comment: yes but  not work any sample

Comment: I dont think so. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226813/how-can-i-decrypt-a-string-using-aes-algorithm-in-c

Comment: 2087C5B4DB21313ED81DA100F5036090 is my encrypted String
and my key is 111
for decode What else is needed?

Comment: you need **IV** if used during encryption.

Comment: IV with which sample of you link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way would be to use the [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class to perform your task in C#.

Here you can find an excellent example on encryption/decryption:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/212707/282649

Let me know...